# creating multiple excel file with web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import httplib2
import pandas as pd
url = "https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_database.html#A"

http = httplib2.Http()

response, content = http.request(url)

links = []

for link in BeautifulSoup(content, features='lxml').find_all('a', href=True):
    if link['href'].startswith("coord") and link['href'].endswith('dat'):
    
        
        links.append(link['href'])
url_data = []
for i in range(len(links)):
    x = 'https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/'+links[i]
    url_data.append(x)

for i in range(len(links)):
    
    #df = pd.read_table(url_data[i], index_col = False, sep='\t')
    
    df =  pd.read_table(url_data[i], header=None, skiprows=1, sep=' ', engine='python')
    
    df.to_excel('data_4.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

I'm trying to save each url data into a separate excel file that will save automatically into a folder. How would I proceed with that? Also, my loops stop at 17th iteration when my list size is 1588 and gives me an error code of

```
raise ParserError(msg)

ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 39, saw 3
```

When there is nothing on line 39

Comment: Remember that it means line 39 in the HTML data you fetched, not line 39 of your code.  You aren't printing the HTML, so you aren't seeing whether that link is formatted slightly differently.

Comment: It also seems that the commands in the last loop can be part of the previous loop. You could write something `df.to_excel(f'data_{i}.xlsx...` to output data of each url to a separate Excel file